# hide icons of Project view in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, android-studio

The Project view of IntelliJ Idea shows two icons next to each Java file:

1. an icon for classes or interfaces (blue or green circle)
2. an icon for the visibility of the file (green lock)

How can I remove these icons?

I had looked into the Preferences but could not find a way to remove them.

(I just moved from Eclipse and I found those colored icons distracting. Less is more.)

[image: Project view in IntelliJ Idea 13]

Comment: In IntelliJ it's impossible